# Python: split line by comma, then by space

Tags: python, string, split

I'm using Python 3 and I need to parse a line like this

```
-1 0 1 0 , -1 0 0 1
```

I want to split this into two lists using `Fraction` so that I can also parse entries like

```
1/2 17/12 , 1 0 1 1
```

My program uses a structure like this

```
from sys import stdin
...
functions'n'stuff
...
for line in stdin:
```

and I'm trying to do

```
for line in stdin:
X = [str(elem) for elem in line.split(" , ")]
num = [Fraction(elem) for elem in X[0].split()]
den = [Fraction(elem) for elem in X[1].split()]
```

but all I get is a list index out of range error: `den = [Fraction(elem) for elem in X[1].split()]
IndexError: list index out of range`

I don't get it. I get a string from `line`. I split that string into two strings at `" , "` and should get one list `X` containing two strings. These I split at the whitespace into two separate lists while converting each element into `Fraction`. What am I missing?
I also tried adding `X[-1] = X[-1].strip()` to get rid of `\n` that I get from ending the line.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing @PadraicCunningham looks like regex may need to be used if both cases need to be accounted for

Comment: Please print out X before you do the subsequent list comprehensions and tell us what the exact value is. Also, you don't need to do `[str(elem) for elem in line.split(' , ')]` Just do `line.split(' , ')`

Comment: `[str(elem) for elem in line.split(" , ")]` is equivalent to `line.split(" , ")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your file has a line without a `" , "` in it, so the split doesn't return 2 elements.

I'd use `split(',')` instead, and then use `strip` to remove the leading and trailing blanks. Note that `str(...)` is redundant, `split` already returns strings.

```
X = [elem.strip() for elem in line.split(",")]
```

You might also have a blank line at the end of the file, which would still only produce one result for `split`, so you should have a way to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

With valid input, your code actually works.

You probably get an invalid line, with too much space or even an empty line or so. So first thing inside the loop, print `line`. Then you know what's going on, you can see right above the error message what the problematic line was.

Or maybe you're not using stdin right. Write the input lines in a file, make sure you only have valid lines (especially no empty lines). Then feed it into your script:

```
python myscript.py < test.txt
```

Comment: Oh. Yes. When I do it with a file, it works. The problem was when I was running without a file, just from the command line. Then I get an empty string as the last one.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
pairs = [line.split(",") for line in stdin]
num = [fraction(elem[0]) for elem in pairs if len(elem) == 2]
den = [fraction(elem[1]) for elem in pairs if len(elem) == 2]
```