# Python Split by line by comma into maps of list

Tags: python

My question is pretty similar to this question
[Python: split line by comma, then by space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30112951/python-split-line-by-comma-then-by-space)

But what I need is one step ahead. My list actually looks like this

```
name,phone,monthlysalary,age
Peter,1234567,100000,28
John,22345,200000,30
Mary,32345,300000,40
```

If I break the list using:-

```
Source="""name,phone,monthlysalary,age
Peter,1234567,100000,28
John,22345,200000,30
Mary,32345,300000,40"""
x = [elem.split(",") for elem in Source.split("\n")]
```

Then I can get the result as:-

```
[['name', 'phone', 'monthlysalary', 'age'],
 ['Peter', '1234567', '100000', '28'],
 ['John', '22345', '200000', '30'],
 ['Mary', '32345', '300000', '40']]
```

But what I need is:-

```
{'Peter': ['1234567', '100000', '28'],
'John': ['22345', '200000', '30'],
'Mary': ['32345', '300000', '40']}
```

Instead of a list of list, I would like to:

1. ignore the header line (name, phone, monthlysalary, age)
2. get the result as a dict of list so that I can use the key name to locate their details
3. It would be great if I can do it in a single line of statement but this is kind of cosmetic

Of coz I can easily write a simple code as below to achieve this:-

```
Source="""name,phone,monthlysalary,age
Peter,1234567,100000,28
John,22345,200000,30
Mary,32345,300000,40"""
x = dict()
_, *lines = Source.split("\n")
for line in lines:
    head, *tail = line.split(',')
    x[head] = tail
```

But instead I would like to know is it possible to achieve this using one liner?

Comment: That looks like a regular CSV file? Have you tried reading it in?

Comment: show your code efforts behind this question

Comment: "get the result as a maps of list" Did you mean a list of dicts?

Comment: Since nobody has pointed out the python docs, here you go: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/csv.html#module-contents Or google a tutorial that explains this module in step by step.

Comment: @sachindubey my bad, not showing my code

Comment: @roganjosh yes, it is, but I do not want to use any CSV library coz I would like to reduce memory requirement as much as possible

Comment: @tobias_k sorry wrong wording, dict of list exactly

Comment: @Mr.T I do not want to use any CSV library coz I would like to reduce memory requirement as much as possible

Answer (score 3):

That's what the CSV module does:

```
import csv

data = csv.DictReader(filename, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thx, but I do not want to use any CSV library coz I would like to reduce memory requirement as much as possible

Comment: That's part of Python's standard library. Not sure what that has to do with memory requirements.

Comment: That would be cool.
But just out of curiosity, could I achieve the same with one liner of python without using csv library?

BTW, the csv.DictReader will return a dict object instead of Dict of List.

Comment: That *is* a one-liner of Python.

Comment: Yup, but this is not a dict of list,
I cannot do something list print(data["Peter"]) to obtain the list 1234567,100000,28

Comment: Then convert it into a dict after reading it: `d = {x[0]: x for x in data}` to get a mapping on the left-most column. In Python, those are called [ist comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). One of the most important parts to learn if you do Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use the `csv` module, you can reproduce the behavious of `DictReader` like this:

```
>>> data = """name,phone,monthlysalary,age
... Peter,1234567,100000,28
... John,22345,200000,30
... Mary,32345,300000,40"""
...
>>> lines = iter(data.splitlines())
>>> head = next(lines).split(",")
>>> [dict(zip(head, line.split(","))) for line in lines]
[{'age': '28', 'monthlysalary': '100000', 'name': 'Peter', 'phone': '1234567'},
 {'age': '30', 'monthlysalary': '200000', 'name': 'John', 'phone': '22345'},
 {'age': '40', 'monthlysalary': '300000', 'name': 'Mary', 'phone': '32345'}]
```

If instead you want a one-liner for the result format from your update, try this:

```
>>> {x[0]: x[1:] for x in (line.split(",") for line in data.splitlines()[1:])}
{'John': ['22345', '200000', '30'],
 'Mary': ['32345', '300000', '40'],
 'Peter': ['1234567', '100000', '28']}
```

However, both the memory consumption of importing the `csv` module and the benefits of one-liners are probably overrated.